# With AWS SAM (configured for NodeJS) how can I use my own functions, imported from a Lambda layer directory, that requires it's own npm packages?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda `index.mjs` handler file where I'm importing a custom function that I wrote like so:

```
import { myCustomFunc } from './opt/my-layer/myCustomFunc.mjs' // no clue where to actually import from due to conflicting docs

export async function handler() {
  myCustomFunc();
}
```

**./layers/my-layer/myCustomFunc.mjs** `sam build` --> **./opt/myCustomFunc.mjs** *(in final build)*

```
import { joi } from 'joi'; // this is an npm package

export function myCustomFunc() {
  console.log(joi.version()); // should log '17.11.0'
}
```

I run `sam build` and `sam local invoke MyLambdaName -my-event.json` locally *(with Docker running)*, but instead of seeing the 'joi' version logged, I get an error:

```
"Cannot find module '/var/opt/nodejs/node_modules/joi' imported from ..."
```

My `template.yaml` config for the Lambda function references two layers with `!Ref`, one for the nodejs packages under `layers/nodejs` and one for my `my-layer` which has `myCustomFunc.mjs`.  But I've tried many different arrangements of my files including putting every file (both node.js and my custom functions) inside the `layers/nodejs` layer and putting the entire node_modules folder at the root of `layers/shared` as well, but it doesn't make a difference. The package is never found in my custom functions.

**Has anyone been able to configure AWS SAM to invoke lambda functions with layers (both locally and in the cloud) that use custom functions that import node packages?**  Can you please share how you did this as I've been stuck on this for two days now.

**I want the simplicity of building and testing the functions locally with AWS SAM (with full access to npm packages), iterating rapidly and only pushing up to the cloud, if tests pass.** I don't want to create .zip layer files, upload the zips, invoke the lambda in the cloud just to see if my layers are configured properly; that's absurd for a larger project and not an answer to my question.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note sure how SAM translates paths, but here's how Lambda works:

1. Layers' directories are mounted into `/opt`
2. NodeJS runtime has NODE_PATH set to `/opt/nodejs/$NODE_VERSION/node_modules/:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/node_modules`

This means that to import something from a layer, you have a choice of:

1. Import it by the absolute path:

   ```
   import { myCustomFunc } from '/opt/…/myCustomFunc.mjs'
   ```

   This way, you can put it anywhere in your layer and just prepend `/opt` to its path in the import
2. Make it into a proper module with structure and put it under `nodejs/node_modules`

   ```
   // /nodejs/node_modules/myCustomFunc/index.js (+package.json and all the jazz)

   import { myCustomFunc } from 'myCustomFunc'
   ```

Once node running your lambda (from within `$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR`) imports and executes code in `myCustomFunc`, it will start looking for `joi`.

It's not a file, so you have no other option as to place it under `/nodejs/node_modules/joi` in your layer.

Technically, you can place it under `node_modules` in every lambda that is using this layer and it will work, but as you can probably guess, it's not a very good solution.